# Microservice Web app - How will I handle User Login in my project management app

Tags: microservices, node.js

I've just started learning to use this architecture and I'm trying to build a simple project management app. The App works such that a user after registering, creates a workspace. This Workspace is made to contain the administrator (The user who creates the workspace) and other users he invites via email. Every user is only affiliated to one workspace for simplicity purposes.

So in the User Model of the Auth Service should I include the workspace id?
For instance,

`const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({workspace:{workspace_id:String})`

What I ought to know is how I'll handle login from there. Should there even be workspace service in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume this's an exercise for learning. If the project is that simple, and it's comprised of a single application only, then MS architecture is overkill.

> The App works such that a user after registering, creates a workspace. This Workspace is made to contain the administrator (The user who creates the workspace) and other users he invites via email. Every user is only affiliated with one workspace for simplicity purposes.

These are business rules; *Tenancy* (ownership) to be precise.

*Tenancy* implies permissions of course, but don't confuse these permissions with those handled by the Auth Service. The Auth service handles permissions at a higher level.

The Auth Service is an orthogonal service, which means, many services or applications (domains) will be integrated with it. It's not exclusive of a single application or services, it belongs to all of them.

For it to be permeable to many integrations, it's important to keep it agnostic to rules specific to the X or Y domain. The opposite subverts the dependency order (makes auth service dependent on everything else).

If every time you add a new domain (service or application)  to the system, you couple the auth service model with the new domain model, when the new domain's rules changes, the auth service is likely to change too. Even if coupling SDLC is not an issue, the risk of introducing regressions due to changes it's.

**So no, you should not add `workspace` to the Auth Service model**.

> What I ought to know is how I'll handle login from there. Should there even be a workspace service in this case?

The Auth service has authenticated the user who has been redirected to the home page. The service has provided the application with an identity model, for example, `Principal`.

`Principal` is agnostic to the application, for example, `principal: {id, username, fullName, email, roles}`.

Now, the application enable  business and authorization rules based on this data.

For example, let's say the app got the following principal:

```json
{
  "id": "1",
  "email": "e@mail.net",
  "username": "laiv",
  "fullName": "Thingol, Elu",
  "roles": ['APP_ROLE_A', 'APP_ROLE_B']
}
```

The application is responsible for

- Mapping `APP_ROLE_A` and `APP_ROLE_B` to concrete access control policies. Anything `App_ROLE_A` is allowed to do is coded in the application.
- Correlating `principal.id` with `workspace` (tenancy). In an MS system, the user will be involved in many more domains; the auth service should not be exposed to all this knowledge, or it will become dependent on all of them.

Now, let's say the app needs to consume a remote service to send a notification. The request will go through the auth service to ensure that the app and the user in session are authorized to send the notification. If both are, the request will hit the service. The service then will inspect the requester (app) and the user (principal) and apply its business rules and security policies to proceed with the notification.

Answer (score 0):

it would be appropriate to include the workspace ID in the User model of the Auth Service. This allows you to associate each user with a specific workspace they belong to.  `const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ email: String, password: String, workspaceId: String, });`

the workspaceId field in the User model, you establish a relationship between the user and the workspace they belong to. This allows you to easily retrieve the workspace information for a particular user when needed.

Regarding the handling of login, you can follow a typical authentication flow where the user provides their email and password during login. After successful authentication, you can retrieve the user's workspace ID from the User model and use it to fetch the corresponding workspace details from the Workspace model. This allows you to set up the user's session and provide access to the appropriate workspace-specific data.